# encoding strings in python

Tags: python, string, encode

I am trying to encode a piece of text that I am getting from an Excel document. It contains all sorts of weird characters like quotation mark, backslashes, parentheses etc. What is the proper way to convert it to Python compatible string so I can process it and write it to a variable?

```
ExampleText = "MINIMUM TRACK FASTENING SHALL BE 0.145" DIAMETER POWDER ACTUATED FASTENERS (P.A.F.S) SPACED ON 8" CENTERS FOR BEARING WALLS, AND AT 12" O.C. FOR NON-LOAD BEARING WALLS (U.N.O.), WITH 1 1/2" MINIMUM PENETRATION INTO CONCRETE. AT X-BRACED SHEAR WALLS, TRACK SHALL BE ATTACHED PER DETAILS.  At Infinity Shear Panels (ISP’S) attach to slab w/ 0.145" x 1 1/2” powder actuated fasteners spaced on 4” centers (HILTI DS 37 P10 or equal) -OR- (6) 3/8" DIA. 2205 expansion anchors w/ 2 1/2" min. embedment - OR-Simpson "Titen" screws  @ 6" o.c."
```

I tried: `str(ExampleText)` but it obviously fails.

Thank you for help!

ps. Here's the error that I get: UnicodeEncodeError: ('unknown', '\x00', 0, 1, '')
ps2. I am on IronPython2.7 i know a bummer :-(

Comment: So you have an `ExampleText` object already?  What type is it (`print type(ExampleText)`)

Comment: its a string object. When i do ExampleText.GetType() it return System.String

Comment: also I get this error UnicodeEncodeError: ('unknown', '\x00', 0, 1, '')

Comment: So the `ExampleText` object isn't in python, it's in like VBA or something -- but you want to use that *value* in a python script?  What about just enclosing the entire string in single quotes: `ExampleText = '"MINIMUM ... o.c."'`

Comment: it doesnt work because of Python string formatting where all of the quotation marks in the text sample cause it to think that there are multiple strings in it as well as backslashes etc.

Comment: There are no single quotes in the string you listed -- if you wrap that string in single quotes, it'll be a start.

Comment: This is just ONE example of thousands of pieces of text and there is no guarantee that there will not be single quotation marks somewhere in them. I would love this solution to be bullet proof if possible and not break at the next line of code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `escape()` function from the `re` package:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.escape(ExampleText)
    '\\"MINIMUM\\ TRACK\\ FASTENING\\ SHALL\\ BE\\ 0.145\\"\\ DIAMETER ...'
>>> ExampleText = ExampleText.decode('string_escape')
    '"MINIMUM TRACK FASTENING SHALL BE 0.145" DIAMETER ...'
```

The `escape()` function will escape all non-alphanumeric characters with their double-backslashed equivalents.  This should handle your input string well.

Answer (score 1):

If the given code precisely matches what you have, it's no wonder it's having problems. You're enclosing it with double quotes, but the string contains double quotes. Left as is, the string will end when the interpreter sees the next double quote, then there will be a bunch of terms it doesn't recognize (like `DIAMETER` and `POWDER`), then eventually another string will begin, and so on.

You need to either escape the string's double quotes with a backslash, or enclose the string with three quotes on each side.

```
ExampleText = "MINIMUM TRACK FASTENING SHALL BE 0.145\" DIAMETER POWDER ACTUATED FASTENERS (P.A.F.S) SPACED ON 8\" CENTERS FOR BEARING WALLS, AND AT 12\" O.C. FOR NON-LOAD BEARING WALLS (U.N.O.), WITH 1 1/2\" MINIMUM PENETRATION INTO CONCRETE. AT X-BRACED SHEAR WALLS, TRACK SHALL BE ATTACHED PER DETAILS.  At Infinity Shear Panels (ISP’S) attach to slab w/ 0.145\" x 1 1/2\" powder actuated fasteners spaced on 4\" centers (HILTI DS 37 P10 or equal) -OR- (6) 3/8\" DIA. 2205 expansion anchors w/ 2 1/2\" min. embedment - OR-Simpson \"Titen\" screws  @ 6\" o.c."
```

or

```
ExampleText = """MINIMUM TRACK FASTENING SHALL BE 0.145" DIAMETER POWDER ACTUATED FASTENERS (P.A.F.S) SPACED ON 8" CENTERS FOR BEARING WALLS, AND AT 12" O.C. FOR NON-LOAD BEARING WALLS (U.N.O.), WITH 1 1/2" MINIMUM PENETRATION INTO CONCRETE. AT X-BRACED SHEAR WALLS, TRACK SHALL BE ATTACHED PER DETAILS.  At Infinity Shear Panels (ISP’S) attach to slab w/ 0.145" x 1 1/2” powder actuated fasteners spaced on 4” centers (HILTI DS 37 P10 or equal) -OR- (6) 3/8" DIA. 2205 expansion anchors w/ 2 1/2" min. embedment - OR-Simpson "Titen" screws  @ 6" o.c."""
```

SO's built-in syntax highlighting indicates that your sample consists of several strings, while mine is one continuous string.

Also, the string contains only forward slashes, no backslashes, so there's no problem there. If there were backslashes and you wanted to resolve that, you would precede the string with an `r` to denote a raw string: `r'hello\nworld` prints as `hello\nworld`. The only thing raw strings can't handle is when the last character in the string is a backslash. Solve that by adding that afterward: `r'C:\Users\jsmith' + '\\'` or `r'C:\Users\jsmith' '\\'` (the `+` isn't strictly necessary when concatenating literal strings).

This is only necessary if you're writing the string into your source code. Strings from external sources like `input()` or files are processed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

From our conversation in comments

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

ExampleText = '"MINIMUM TRACK FASTENING SHALL BE 0.145" DIAMETER POWDER ACTUATED FASTENERS (P.A.F.S) SPACED ON 8" CENTERS FOR BEARING WALLS, AND AT 12" O.C. FOR NON-LOAD BEARING WALLS (U.N.O.), WITH 1 1/2" MINIMUM PENETRATION INTO CONCRETE. AT X-BRACED SHEAR WALLS, TRACK SHALL BE ATTACHED PER DETAILS.  At Infinity Shear Panels (ISP’S) attach to slab w/ 0.145" x 1 1/2” powder actuated fasteners spaced on 4” centers (HILTI DS 37 P10 or equal) -OR- (6) 3/8" DIA. 2205 expansion anchors w/ 2 1/2" min. embedment - OR-Simpson "Titen" screws  @ 6" o.c."'

print(ExampleText)
```

The coding header line is required since you have non-ascii characters in there.

You could also wrap the literal with `'''` or `"""`:

```
x = '''some string'''
x = """some string"""
```

Note that a better solution might be to get the string directly from the data instead of copying/pasting into your code using a package like [csv](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).